# MySQL query with join optimization

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I got a query:

`SELECT a.nick,grp,count(*) FROM help_mails h JOIN accounts a ON h.helper=a.id WHERE closed=1 GROUP BY helper, grp, a.nick`

What is wrong with this join?
When I made 2 queries:

`SELECT helper,grp,count(*) FROM help_mails h WHERE closed=1 GROUP BY helper, grp;
SELECT nick FROM accounts WHERE id IN (...)`
It is 100 times faster.

EXPLAIN returns this:

```
id     select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  h   ref     closed  closed  1   const   1846    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  a   ref     PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   margonem.h.helper   1   Using where; Using index
```

accounts.id, help_mails.grp and help_mails.closed got indexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that your first query is not same as the second ones.

If you have same `NICK` for two `account`'s, `COUNT(*)`'s for these accounts will be merged together in the first query and returned separately in the second one.

If you want separate `COUNT`'s for separate `account`'s to be always returned, you may combine your queries into one:

```
SELECT  a.nick, gpr, cnt
FROM    (
        SELECT  helper, grp, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM    help_mails h
        WHERE   closed = 1
        GROUP BY
                helper, grp
        ) ho
JOIN    accounts a
ON      a.id = ho.helper
```

or change a `GROUP BY` condition for the first query:

```
SELECT  a.nick, grp, count(*)
FROM    help_mails h
JOIN    accounts a
ON      h.helper = a.id
WHERE   closed = 1
GROUP BY
        helper, grp, a.id, a.nick
```

Building a composite index on `help_mails (closed, helper, grp)` will help you a lot, since it will be used in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks :) The first query with inner select works fast as it should :)

Comment: Thinker: it will work even faster if you create a composite index :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what's wrong is that help_mails.helper isn't indexed.

Comment: Adding index to helper field doesn't improve anything, I checked it.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me, but okay.  Try a compound key on closed and helper.